# Looking to retrieve objective data in flat format from a mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, hierarchy

I'm looking for a way to retrieve objective data stored in a mysql database, in one query (as flat data).

Below, are two objects, which represent two "User" objects in my test data:

```
{
    instanceId: 1,
    name: bob,
    pass: passbob,
    favouriteBook: {
        instanceId: 2,
        name: karma,
        description: saucy,
        author: {
            instanceId: 3,
            name: peter,
            age: 30
        }
    },
    allBooks: [
        {
            instanceId: 2,
            name: karma,
            description: saucy,
            author: {
                instanceId: 3,
                name: peter,
                age: 30
            }
        },
        {
            instanceId: 4,
            name: sutra,
            description: fancy,
            author: {
                instanceId: 5,
                name: john,
                age: 41
            }
        },
    ]
},
{
    instanceId: 6,
    name: ken,
    pass: kenpass,
    favouriteBook: {
        instanceId: 4,
        name: sutra,
        description: fancy,
        author: {
            instanceId: 5,
            name: john,
            age: 41
        }
    },
    allBooks: [
        {
            instanceId: 2,
            name: karma,
            description: saucy,
            author: {
                instanceId: 3,
                name: peter,
                age: 30
            }
        },
        {
            instanceId: 4,
            name: sutra,
            description: fancy,
            author: {
                instanceId: 5,
                name: john,
                age: 41
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Note that both "User" objects use the same structure. This is because the objects are required to follow a strict structure (defined by the application, not by the database). Also note that both objects re-use certain other objects, where the re-used objects retain their "instanceId". This is important.

I am storing this data in a mysql database, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testinstanceproperties` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `instanceId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `instanceId` (`instanceId`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

INSERT INTO `testinstanceproperties` (`id`, `instanceId`, `name`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'name', 'bob'),
(2, 1, 'pass', 'passbob'),
(3, 2, 'name', 'karma'),
(4, 2, 'description', 'saucy'),
(5, 3, 'name', 'peter'),
(6, 3, 'age', '30'),
(7, 4, 'name', 'sutra'),
(8, 4, 'description', 'fancy'),
(9, 5, 'name', 'john'),
(10, 5, 'age', '41'),
(11, 6, 'name', 'ken'),
(12, 6, 'pass', 'kenpass');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testinstances` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

INSERT INTO `testinstances` (`id`, `type`) VALUES
(3, 'Author'),
(5, 'Author'),
(2, 'Book'),
(4, 'Book'),
(1, 'User'),
(6, 'User');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testtree` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `leftInstanceId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rightInstanceId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `leftToRightProperty` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `leftInstanceId` (`leftInstanceId`,`rightInstanceId`,`leftToRightProperty`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

INSERT INTO `testtree` (`id`, `leftInstanceId`, `rightInstanceId`, `leftToRightProperty`) VALUES
(11, NULL, 1, NULL),
(12, NULL, 6, NULL),
(3, 1, 2, 'allBooks'),
(1, 1, 2, 'favouriteBook'),
(4, 1, 4, 'allBooks'),
(2, 2, 3, 'author'),
(6, 4, 5, 'author'),
(7, 6, 2, 'allBooks'),
(8, 6, 4, 'allBooks'),
(5, 6, 4, 'favouriteBook');
```

- the "testTree" table stores the relationships of each object instance. Note that we store the leftInstanceId (the instanceId of the parent object), the rightInstanceId (the instanceId of the child object) and the leftToRightProperty (the property that links the parent object to the child object). Effectively, we are storing the parent>property>child relationships in this table.
- the "testInstances" table stores the instances. It ultimately creates an instance of an object type by creating a new instanceId, against an object type.
- the "testInstanceProperties" table stores **basic** properties of an instance. Note that properties that have objects assigned to them are not stored here.

---

The ultimate goal, as stated initially, is to be able to retrieve the object data in a flat format, in one query. The query should be able to find either one object by id, or all objects of a certain type. Below are some examples:

[image: data image sheet]

Note that the "baseInstanceId" and "depth" values don't exist as hard values in the data. So it would be great if the solution were able to calculate these values while the data is being retrieved.

---

The **Nested set** formula will not work for this solution. The reason being, a property that accepts objects can either accept one object, or many, and this can happen at any depth within the hierarchy. Nested sets simply don't support this sort of complexity.

I have also tried recursion at client-level. I initially built a system that handled this type of data quite well, by initially retrieving the base object(s), and then recursively finding the child objects of the base object, until there were no more child objects to find. This worked fine for small implementations, however even slightly moderately sized data sets (a few hundred thousand rows) struggled in terms of performance, due to the recursion. So ultimately, I am looking to avoid recursion if at all possible!

I would appreciate any suggestions on how this could be done.

Comment: You can't do this in MySQL with a query (I mean something which would start from SELECT), not easily. You can do this with single inheritance line (an instance can be a child to only one parent), but not multiple. It's possible to write a stored procedure which would do this and return a recordset (if your ORM supports calling stored procedures), or, alternatively, do the recursion and cache each instance on the client side. The second way is the cleanest one.

Comment: @Quassnoi thanks for the info. Yeah, i'm making the same considerations as we speak. I'm thinking that a mixture of both client and data-side caching would be the best option in attempting to greatly improve the ability to retrieve objective data. Thanks again.